# paste special value to another multiple excel files with python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I tried to use glob twice so it can copy and paste to multiple files. But this thing copy the first data only and print all of the data same from the first one to last one. I wanna copy the first to the different folder first data, then second to the different folder second data, and so on. Thanks for any help in advance

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import glob

ws = 'OUTPUT'
ws2 = 'Original data'
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

for filename in glob.glob("D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding*.xlsx"):
    data = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    data.Worksheets(ws).Range('F1:H500').Copy()
    for filename2 in glob.glob("D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding2/sounding*.xlsx"):
        copy = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename2)
        copy.Worksheets(ws2).Range('A1:C500').PasteSpecial(Paste=-4163)
```

example
[image]
copy the value from sounding001_out

[image]
then paste special value in sounding001

then do it again to sounding_002 to sounding002, and so on

Comment: Can you clarify with examples what do you mean to obtain, and what you are obtaining?

Comment: I editted the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to copy from `sounding001_out` to `sounding001`, from `sounding002_out` to `sounding002`, etc.
Then, you have to use a single loop, and set string values for your filenames suitably.
For the case you posted,

```
filename2 = filename.replace( '_', '' ).replace( 'Sounding', 'Sounding2' )
```

should work (removing the inner loop). For other cases, you have to refer to documentation on Python strings

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: is there a way to put different path? because right now both files is in the same folder. Thanks

Comment: @lalalala - Of course. See edit. Please check the documentation referred to for other handling of strings.